# Angular promise between two functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I've got two functions

```
var firstFunction = function(aPromise) {
    //Do stuff

    return aPromise.resolve();
}


var secondFunction = function(i) {

    var defer = $q.defer;

    //Do stuff with i (an index) - used for anadromic calls.

    firstFunction(defer).promise.then(function() {

        i++;
        secondFunction(i);

    })

}
```

I need the second function to wait the promise from the first function to call itslef.
Is this syntax correct ?

After request I add the purpose of my code.

I've got:

Categories > Products > Favourites which I have to call from server.

For each category I have to get the products and for each product I have to check if it is favourite. The bad thing is that in current situation I've got to make many calls which are all asynchronous and one have to wait the other.

Comment: what is the `i` in second function?

Comment: an index which is used for functionality

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code, which is working for me. I am calling this code in a different method, which is waiting till I get the response from server

```
var promise = [XYZService.locations($scope.newrecord.state.Text)]
$q.all(promise).then(function (data) {
$scope.addnewrecord.locations = data[0];
});
```

Here, based on state I am getting respective locations from server and binding that locations to a model

Answer (score 0):

I think shouldn't send defer like parameter in `firstFunction()` and `var defer = $q.defer;` must be `var defer = $q.defer();`

If want to get data from service you can using `resolve` in AngularJS, read explain article here: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/. I hope it can help you.